# NSDate from string (safely)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am struggling to find a way to parse a NSDate from string where if it goes wrong it crash the app.

As an example, the following date would cause a crash: Wed, 12 Marc 2014 17:13:54 +00000\n\t\t\t\

I am currently using the following code:

```
let trimmed  = unformatedDate.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz"

if let tempDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(trimmed) {

      print(tempDate)

} else { print("We have an error with the tempCreatedDate") }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying you want it to crash the app if it fails?

Comment: @NDoc, the OP's sample date is an example of a string that would FAIL to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should not cause a crash. Rather, the `dateFromString` method returns an optional which will be `nil` if the input string doesn't match the specified date format. You need to code defensively for that case, as you have done.

Where you'd crash is if you force-unwrapped the resulting optional. You're using optional binding, which is a good way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your date format `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS"` doesn't match your date string `"Tue, 12 Jul 2011 20:18:26 GMT"`. You need to use a different date format.

Comment: I am concerned about edge cases where I am getting data that doesn't fit the expected date format.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
func nsDateFromString(myDate:String)-> NSDate{
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" //format style. Browse online to get a format that fits your needs.
    let dateString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(myDate)
    return dateString!
}
```